# Graph visualization in C#

Tags: c#, graph, data-visualization, drawing

I'm currently learning swarm intelligence algorithms and I want write a C# app for testing those in the context of a vehicle routing problem.

I want to write an app that will show a graph that will be a representation of of cities (vertices) and roads (edges) and implement new algorithms as I learn more of them.

The problem is I don't know how I can draw such graph. I was thinking about using adjacency matrix to know if the vertices are connected and another to represent the distance between them if they are connected.

If You know any way to visualize such graph in a efficient way it will be much appreciated. I saw someone was able to do so using picture box which is mind blowing.

Comment: Can you add a tag for the .Net UI you want to use, like for example `winforms`or `wpf`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is probably to create a winforms application and attach an event handler for your [paint-event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/custom-painting-drawing?view=netdesktop-6.0). This will give you a graphics object that can be used to draw squared, lines etc. Note that you probably need to translate your coordinates from your internal coordinate system to screen/image coordinates.